# Iterate worksheets in a workbook in a manner like each worksheet filter header value display in a similar format

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have 75 worksheets with most of the worksheets are consistent header and few of them are not. see below

```
SiteMap_Reference | Test_Case_ID | Test_Case_Name | Expected
```

OR

```
Test_Case_Id | Test_Case_Name| Step_name| Expected
```

OR

```
Test_Case_Id |  Test_Case_Name | Expected
```

So all 75 difference worksheets having 3 or 4 different types of rows which are similar but not in an order manner compare to others.

My objective is to get the common header values from each worksheet in below manner,

Test_Case_Name : 
Description : 
Expected: 
Step_number: 
Also, 
The API which responsible to parse` will accept only 2 fields as below;

```
Test Case Name -> "name"
Description -> "description"
author -> "dbhati" (hardcoded)
folder_id -> 1 (hardcoded)
```

I have written a code which is accepting only one worksheet and displaying result;

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
# Demonstrates basic xlrd functions for working with Excel files
import json
from markdown.odict import OrderedDict
import xlrd

# Open the workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('RegressionComplete.xls')

print "\nThe number of worksheets is", wb.nsheets 
print "\nWorksheet name(s):\n", wb.sheet_names()  

worksheets = wb.sheet_names()

# Get sheet either by index or by name
'''45th worksheet will have below header row;
['Test Case Name', 'Test Case ID', 'Description', 'Expected', 'Status']'''
currentSheet = wb.sheet_by_index(45)   

#ketera_dict = {'author' : 'dbhati', 'folder_id' : 3, 'description' : '', 'step_name' : '', 'expected' : ''}

# read header values into the list    
header_cols = [currentSheet.cell(1, col_index).value for col_index in xrange(currentSheet.ncols)]
print header_cols

# List to hold dictionaries
testcase_list = []

# Iterate through each row in worksheet and fetch values into dict
for rownum in range(2, currentSheet.nrows):

    tests = OrderedDict()
    row_values = currentSheet.row_values(rownum)

    tests['author'] = "dbhati"
    tests['folder_id'] = 1

    if (row_values[2] == 'Test Case Name'):
        tests['name'] = row_values[2]
        if (row_values[3] == "Step_name"):
            tests['description']  = "\nDescription:\n" + row_values[4] + "\n\nStep Name (Procedures): \n" + row_values[3] +"\n\nExpected Results:\n" + row_values[5] 
            print "debug 1"
        else:
            tests['description']  = "\nDescription:\n" + row_values[3] + "\n\nStep Name (Procedures): \n" +"\n\nExpected Results:\n" + row_values[4] 
            print "debug 2"   
    elif (row_values[1] == 'Test Case Name'):
        tests['name'] = row_values[1]
        tests['description']  = "\n\nStep Name (Procedures):\n" + row_values[2] + "\nDescription:\n" + row_values[3] + "\n\nExpected Results:\n" + row_values[4] 
        print "debug 3"
    else:
        #worksheet 45th will come in this block of else.
        tests['name'] = row_values[0]
        tests['description']  = "\nDescription:\n" + row_values[2] + "\n\nExpected Results:\n" + row_values[3] 
        print "debug 4"
        print currentSheet.name 

    testcase_list.append(tests)

# Serialize the list of dicts to JSON
jsonFormat = json.dumps(testcase_list)

#Write to file
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(jsonFormat)
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you've written? Where are you stuck? (Also, it looks like a lot of that code is completely unrelated to the problem—for example, I doubt you need the JSON encoding to demonstrate or debug the problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on what code to post in your questions.)

Comment: I am parsing excel data into JSON, however that might not cause any problem.

Comment: How does that answer my questions?

Comment: Now code is more readable, but for each worksheet, the if else block is executing  tests['name'] = row_values[0] bock which seems wired. Even tests['name'] != row_values[0].

Comment: Well, if you assign `tests['name'] = row_values[2]`, then check `tests['name'] == row_values[0]`, and none of your sample formats generally have the same data in columns 0 and 2… why are you surprised by that? More importantly, you still haven't actually explained what you want help with.